# Uploading an image to a server in android

Tags: java, php, android, image, upload

I my app I am trying to send an image over a PHP server. The problem is the PHP programmers say that it should be sent as an data. Following is the code which I am currently using, please help me to convert the image to a data and get a response from the server.

```
InputStream is;
    private int serverResponseCode;
    private String serverResponseMessage;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) 
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        DataInputStream inputStream = null;

        String pathToOurFile = "/sdcard/siva.PNG";
        Log.e("pathToOurFile",""+pathToOurFile);

        String urlServer = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/upload.php";
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary =  "*****";
        Log.e("URL Server",""+urlServer);

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
        Log.e("maxBufferSize",""+maxBufferSize);

        try
        {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile) );
            Log.e("FIS",""+fileInputStream);
            URL url = new URL(urlServer);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    //  Allow Inputs & Outputs
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);

            // Enable POST method
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

            outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // Read file
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            Log.e("con",String.valueOf(connection.getDoOutput()));

            serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
            Log.e("response",""+serverResponseCode);
            Log.e("serverResponseMessage",""+serverResponseMessage);

            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("Exception Handling",""+ex);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast i found the answer, i did a small mistake....In the above code i have changed only one word in the following line

outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"**uploadedfile**\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);

In the above line the main part is the word "uploadedfile". This word must be specified by the php programmer or else the file which we are sending will not be replaced.

Please refer the [here](http://katharnavas.blogspot.com/2009/10/upload-files-from-mobile.html)